# Indy idHTTP continue execution after error

Tags: indy, idhttp

I have an indy IDHTTP component which is called repeatedly using a timer (4-5 times a second)

I have a poor internet connection so occasionally there are timeout problems or garbage responses that cause an error with the idHTTP component.

I have a try except finally clause around the component but when an error occurs the code shows an error and execution stops.

I know what causes the errors, its my poor internet connection, but what i want to do is just ignore the invalid response or error and just continue so that my program doesn't break.

Comment: What exactly happens when you try to continue and it doesn’t work? Please be more specific. Provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting these errors because of a poor internet connection, I can't fix that.  The code is used to access the Betfair API so advising Betfair won't help.